# Babel not transpiling npm link/symlink package source code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

I´m setting up a shared module environment using node. Here is my directory structure:

```
project
 |--common
 |    |--package.json
 |    |--graphql
 |          |----schema.js
 |
 |--server
     |--package.json
     |--server.js
```

Linking both projects:

```
$ cd project\common
$ npm link
```

Then:

```
$ cd ../server
$ npm link common
```

`common` `Package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "private": true,
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "description": "Common code for all projects",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

`server` `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"babel-node start-server\" \"babel-node start-client\"",
    "server": "nodemon --exec \"babel-node start-server.js\"",
    "client": "nodemon --exec \"babel-node start-client.js\"",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "common": "file:../common",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-graphql": "^0.6.12",
    "graphql": "^0.13.1",
    "graphql-relay": "^0.5.4",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.10",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "validator": "^9.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.5.1",
    "eslint": "^4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.7.0",
    "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "stage-0",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-runtime"
    ]
  }
}
```

Server.js code:

```
import schema from "common/graphql/schema";
...
```

Running server application:

```
$ npm run server
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at loader (D:\project\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\project\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/9. DEV/WORKSPACE/amplifactory/server/routes.js:25:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at loader (D:\project\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\project\server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

From what I´ve seen that is not transpiling code outside `server` directory, but without putting `common` ouside `server` directory I cannot build my shared code.

How to solve this babel issue and make it transpile correctly ?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't going to like it, and maybe there is a better answer in spring 2018, but you may need to have a separate build step for your common code.  I have a similar project where the package.json file for the common code looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "stripmall_gcloud_services",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "wraps up some commonly used google helpers",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "standard --fix && mocha -r babel-register",
    "build": "babel lib -d dist"
  }...}
```

Notice the npm build step that transpiles the common code, and notice that the main key points to the index.js file in the transpiled directory.  You just run **npm run build** whenever you update your common code and all your linking will work as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Moskal for the post. In fact, as you said, this is not a solution, but a workaround. I´wil lplay around a little bit with this...

Comment: I look forward to seeing a solution.  On new projects, I've pretty much stopped transpiling my server side code and am living with the old style exports.

Comment: Did you ever find a better way?